# Why doesn't the 'fullbleed' layout attribute work in this snippet?

Tags: layout, polymer

I am trying to have a full screen paper-header-panel..

- Browser: Firefox v35
- OS: Linux
- Polymer: v1.4

The content area goes behind the header region. Notice the red border around the body tag:

[image: Should work]

If I explicitly set `body height:100vh`, the body tag stretches, but the green region won't 'flex'
[image]

What am I missing here?

Also on Chrome v49 64bit, the page renders like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
    <style>
        .icon-snooze {
            color: red;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html" />

    <style is="custom-style" include='iron-flex'>
        body {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        paper-header-panel {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .content {
            border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
        }
        .moContent {
            background-color: var(--paper-light-green-500);
        }

        .blue .paper-header {
            background-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class='fullbleed vertical layout'>

    <paper-header-panel class="blue">

        <paper-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="icons:menu"></paper-icon-button>
            <div>My snazzy toolbar</div>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <div class='content vertical layout'>
            <iron-icon icon="av:snooze" class="icon-snooze"></iron-icon>
            <div class='moContent flex'>More content</div>
            <div>Footer</div>
    </paper-header-panel>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: Just a bunch of 'no element found' & 'not well formed' coming from various polymer files (which I didn't modify.. so assuming they are not a problem.)

Comment: The non-flexing issue is unrelated to `fullbleed` and should probably go into its own question for better answers. But in my tests, setting the height of the flexed element's container (`.content`) allows the element to flex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use `fullbleed`, make sure to include the `iron-positioning` module in a custom style tag:

```
<link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
<style is="custom-style" include="iron-positioning"></style>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
  <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-positioning"></style>
  <style>
    body {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
  Hello world!
</body>
```

This requirement is currently undocumented (at least it's not explicitly stated in the [docs for `fullbleed`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout#full-bleed-lt-body-gt-)).

Comment: iron-positioning it is! How did you find this out ? Still no flex :(

Comment: @Gishu I looked at the source of `iron-flex-layout-classes.html` and saw that `body.fullbleed` was defined in `iron-positioning`. I filed a documentation bug.